# php preg_match starts with keyword

Tags: php, preg-match, keyword

Surely an easy problem, but I can't get is solved...

I just want to detect if my sql query is starting with a "select" or anything else.
This code seems not to work :

```
if (preg_match("/^(select)/i", $sql) > 0)
{
// SELECT query
}
else
{
// other query
}
```

Thanks for your help !

[EDIT]
Ok, I have the root cause: 
I may have spaces, tabs and line returns before the keyword "select"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I got it :

```
preg_match("/[\s]*(select)/i", $sql)
```

Thanks for your answers anyway !

Answer (score 9):

A regular expression isn't necessary, use [stripos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php)

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = 1";

if (stripos(trim($query), "SELECT") === 0)
    echo "Query begins with $str";
else
    echo "Query DOES NOT begin with $str";

// Notice: trim() will remove whitespace before and after your $query string.
```

**Ex**: http://ideone.com/hLaBq

Alternatively, if you want to stick with [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
if (preg_match("/^select (.*)/i", trim($query)) > 0) {
    //...
```

**Ex**: http://ideone.com/fzh2I

Comment: I guess it would work, but I would like to stick to preg_match(), thx anyway

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
if (preg_match("/^[[:space:]]*select/i", $sql))
```

This will match any (or no) white space between the start and the `select`, so your spaces, tabs, etc. are accounted for.

Update, it may be this on your system:

```
if (preg_match("/^\s*select/i", $sql))
```